# Using scientific notation and underscore kind specifier at the same time for real literals in Fortran

Tags: fortran, double, fortran-iso-c-binding, fortran2003

Using scientific notation for floating point literals is easy enough in Fortran:

`1.5d-10`

would mean a double precision (whatever that means under current Fortran compiler settings) floating point value that approximates `1.5*10^-15`.

However, the fusion of the exponent notation and the floating point kind specifier is a bit of an issue. How would one declare this floating point literal when one wants it to have a type of `C_DOUBLE`?

I know that this is a bit of a nitpicking issue, but there can be circumstances when double precision will not be the same as `C_DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A real literal may be specified by any of the following forms:

- `1.2`
- `1.2e0`
- `1.2d0`
- `1.2_kind`
- `1.2e0_kind`

This final one is an example of using a kind specifier and an exponent.  So, specific to the question: `1.5e-15_C_DOUBLE`.

There certainly can be cases where `1.5d-15` is not the same as `1.5e-15_C_DOUBLE`.  The kind of a double precision and `real(C_DOUBLE)` are choices by the Fortran and companion C compilers respectively.

Compilers which allow single and double precision literal constants to be promoted to higher kinds by a compiler flag won't touch `real(C_DOUBLE)`.

---

For real values which have no decimal part, there are additional available forms:

- `1.`
- `1e0`
- `1.e0`
- `1d0`
- `1.d0`
- `1.e0_kind`
- `1e0_kind`

That is, the decimal part is optional, and if an exponent is given the decimal separator is also optional.  Note however that `1` is an integer literal, while `1e0` and similar are real.